# How to use HystrixCommand inside a spring AOP class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, hystrix

in my current project, I'm required to use Hystrix for request fallback handling(mainly on request timeout fallback). I have tested a simple case, which is putting the @HystrixCommand annotation above one spring rest controller method, like the one below:

```
@RestController
public class xxxxxx {

    @RequestMapping(value = "xxxxxxx")
        @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallback", commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "2000"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "2000")
    })
    public String xxxxxx(@RequestParam(value = "xxxx", required = true) String xxxx) {
        ....
        return json.toString();
    }

}
```

This works pretty well. Timeout is triggerred after 2 seconds and it goes into the fallback method I predefined. Now the problem comes: There are too many methods in on controller and there are many controllers in the project. Copy&paste the @HystrixCommand method by method would not be a good idea, and I'm required to implement it by spring aop.
Then I wrote something as below:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class TimeoutMonitor {

    @Pointcut("execution(xxxxxxxx)")
    public void excuteService() {}

    @Around("excuteService()")
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallback", commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "2000"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "2000")
    })
    public Object monitor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
        try {
            Object output = pjp.proceed();
            return output;
        }catch(Throwable e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @HystrixCommand
    public String fallback(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("message", "request timeout");
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

And it's not working... The fallback method is never reached

During the debugging, I have made sure that the logic flow goes through the flow of excuteService()->monitor()->matched method, and it's already passing 2 seconds, but the fallback method is never reached. I have researched on this problem and find that @HystrixCommand is also implemented by AOP. I guess putting one aop in another is the reason that causes this problem, but unfortunately I can't think of an approach to resolve it.

I would be grateful if someone can provide a solution. Solutions not implemented by aop are also admitted, but absolutely copy&paste @HystrixCommand above each method is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is still no response to this question, I will put my own temporary solution here.

First of all, use hystrix inside spring aop is still not workable, so the only efforts are on reducing affections on controller side. Hystrix allow default timeout setup inside springboot application.properties file like this:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=3000
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds=3000
```

In this way the annotations needed to put above each method is reduced to only one line:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallback")
```

This is still not concise in these points:

- Need to copy/paste this annotation for every method
- Need to copy/paste the fallback method in every place hystrix is used
- For hystrix fallback method itself, the parameter type and number need to be exactly same with the hystrix marked method. Currently I'm using several overloading method called 'fallback' for this, in each controller

Although still not as concise as I exptcted, this is all I can think of currently. Will perform update once I find better solutions.